# Ionic cordova responsive web site to mobile app?

Tags: cordova, responsive-design, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want do develope a mobile app for ios and android, via ionic or cordova.  At the top of the app should it have header/top bar and side menu(with slide option) .

And the rest of this app should show a responsive webpage from the internet. Is it possible to do that without iframe tag, because some of performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can develop a fully function mobile app using Cordova or Ionic.  How you design it (menu bar, etc.) is completely up to you.  You DO NOT have to use iFrames as Cordova and Ionic allow you to local your assets (html, javascript, css) locally.  Meaning, the web pages you load in Cordova are local to the device the app is running on.

Comment: Let me know if his helped/answered.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, here is a [link](http://showcase.ionicframework.com/apps/top) containing some apps developed using ionic. They are all responsive and works across multiple devices, operating systems and form factors (which is pretty much what hybrid development is intended to do).

The styling of the components of a hybrid development framework are responsive by default unless you override the css that may interfere with the responsiveness.

You need to understand that since it's plain css that govern the look and feel of the application, you have the freedom to manipulate it to do whatever you want as Steve correctly mentioned.

And yes, you do **not** need to use iFrames (they're old school now... ) but nothing restricts you from using them if really needed.